# Exponential extension of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: exponential-function

A non-trivial exponential function $E:\mathbb{K} \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ in a field $\mathbb{K}$  is a function such that

\begin{split}
E(x+y)=E(x)E(y) \quad \forall x,y \in \mathbb{K} \\
E(x)=1 \iff x=0
\end{split}

For the exponential function such that $E(1)=a \in \mathbb{K}$ write $E_a(X)=a^x$.
We know that if $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{Q}$ such a function can not be defined as $a^{\frac{m}{n}} $ 
can be irrational, and  $E_a(x) \notin \mathbb{Q}$.

Call *exponential extension* of $\mathbb{Q}$ an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ in which we can define an exponential function. We know that  $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Q}$ are such exponential extension. But it can be shown that there is no exponential extension $\mathbb{E}/\mathbb{Q}$ whith $ \mathbb{E}\subset \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{E}\ne \mathbb{R}$?
I can not find such a demonstration.

(Sorry for my bad English).

Comment: Aren't the algebraic numbers such an extension? If $a,q \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $a \geq 0$ then $a^q$ is an algebraic number.

Comment: @Ian, but $2^\sqrt2$ is transcendent.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Good point.

Comment: I don't think $\mathbb C/\mathbb Q$ is such an extension, because $\exp(2\pi i)=1$ while $2\pi i\neq0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let be
$$\Bbb E_0=\Bbb Q$$
$$B_1=\{2^r\,|\, r\in\Bbb E_0\}$$
$$\Bbb E_1=\Bbb E_0(B_1)$$
$$B_2=\{2^r\,|\, r\in\Bbb E_1\}$$
$$\Bbb E_2=\Bbb E_1(B_2)$$
$$\cdots$$
$$\Bbb E=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\Bbb E_n$$
and $\Bbb E\ne\Bbb R$ because is countable.

Comment: Pérez Pinilla: but you can show that $\mathbb{E}$ is a field? Is $2+2^\sqrt{2}$ in $\mathbb{E}$?

Comment: @EmilioNovati, is a increasing union of fields. If $x,y\in\Bbb E$, then $x,y\in\Bbb E_n$ for $n$ large enough.

Comment: @EmilioNovati, I've corrected my post.

Comment: @EmilioNovati Just in case, $\mathbb{E}_1(B_2)$ is the field extension of $\mathbb{E}_1$ by $B_2$, in other words it's the smallest subfield of (say) $\mathbb{C}$ containing $\mathbb{E}_1$ and $B_2$. In particular it contains, by definition, $2 + 2^{\sqrt{2}}$, because $2 \in \mathbb{E}_1$ and $2^\sqrt{2} \in B_2$ (and this because $\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{E}_1$).

Comment: Seem you need to specify which choice of $2^r$ you want when $r$ is not an integer.

Comment: @KevinCarlson, true. Taking $2^r>0$ is the easier choice.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much! 
If I have well understood: for each $a \in \mathbb{Q}$ we can build a field 
$$ 
\mathbb{E}_a=\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}_{a,n} 
$$
such that $E: \mathbb{E}_a \rightarrow  \mathbb{E}_a$, $E_a(x)=a^x \quad \forall x \in  \mathbb{E}_a$ is a well defined exponential function.
Now the problem becomes: 
the field closures of the sets 
$$
\mathbb{E}=\bigcup_{a \in\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{E}_a \varsubsetneq \mathbb{C} \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad
\mathbb{E}^+=\bigcup_{a \in\mathbb{Q}^+}\mathbb{E}_a \varsubsetneq \mathbb{R}
$$
are are proper subsets of $\mathbb{C}, \mathbb{R}$ ?

And I get a further question: the Napier's constant  $e$ is an element of $\mathbb{E}^+$?
And, more generally, there is a method to determine if a transcendental number $ \in \mathbb{E}$?

Comment: Verifying the proof I have another question. How can I prove that $\mathbb{E}_i$ is countable?

Comment: About countability: every element of $\Bbb K(x_1,x_2,\cdots)$ can be written as a quotient of polynomials with coefficients in $\Bbb K$.

Comment: @Martin-Blas Pérez Pinilla Yes !!! Thankyou

Comment: I've corrected my post because $ \{\mathbb{E}_a\}$ is not a chain of fields.

Comment: Please ask your new question as a new question, with a link to this one if it helps provide context.

Comment: Sorry... the new question is at [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1006237/the-exponential-extension-of-mathbbq-is-a-proper-subset-of-mathbbc).