# The exponential extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ is a proper subset of $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, exponential-function, extension-field

This question come from a recent post  [Exponential extension of $\mathbb{Q}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992463/exponential-extension-of-mathbbq).

An exponential field is a field $\mathbb{K}$ where it's well defined a function $E:\mathbb{K} \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ such that:
$$
E(x+y)=E(x)E(y) \quad \forall x,y \in \mathbb{K}  \quad \land \quad E(0)=1 
$$
In the preceding post, thanks to the answer of Martìn-Blas Pérez Pinilla, it's showed that $ \forall a\in \mathbb{Q}$ we can build an exponential field $\mathbb{E}_a$ in which is well defined the exponential function $E_a(r): \mathbb{E}_a \rightarrow \mathbb{E}_a \;;\; E_a(r)=a^r$.
Now consider the field:
$$
 \mathbb{E}=\left \langle \bigcup_{a \in\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{E}_a \right\rangle \subset \mathbb{C}
$$
that is the field closure in $\mathbb{C}$ of all $\mathbb{E}_a$.
This is an exponential field and the question is: is $\mathbb{E}$ a proper subset of $ \mathbb{C}$  or it's  $\mathbb{E}= \mathbb{C}$?

Others sub-questions are:

there is a method to determine if a transcendental number $ \in \mathbb{E}$?

the Napier's constant  $e$ is an element of $\mathbb{E}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this answer it's proved that $\Bbb E$ is countable, so yes, it is a proper subset of $\Bbb C$. And of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: The point being that $\mathbb{E}_a$ is countable for each $a$.

Comment: OK!.But the problem is that $\{\mathbb{E}_a|a∈\mathbb{Q}\}$ is not a tower of fields. So I'm not sure that his field closure is countable.