# Prove that $ exp_{a}(\frac{p}{q}) = \sqrt[q]{a^{p}} \space \forall \space p,q \in \mathbb{Z} $

Tags: induction, exponential-function, exponentiation, radicals

Prove that $ exp_{a}(\frac{p}{q}) = \sqrt[q]{a^{p}} \space \forall \space p,q \in \mathbb{Z} $ with $ q \geq 2 $

I'm not sure how to approach this question. I was thinking through in induction with base case $ q = 2 $ but there is also the $p$ variable.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I take it that your notation $exp_a(p/q)$ means $a^{p/q}$. In which case, the question arises, how are you defining $a^{p/q}$? One way to define it is as $\root q\of{a^p}$, in which case your problem disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by @Gerry Myerson the problem disappear if you simply define:
$$
 a^{\frac{p}{q}}:= \sqrt[q]{a^p} =x \quad such \;that \quad x^q=a^p
$$

but this seems to be a trick to avoid the problem by a suitable definition that is justified by the exponential rules for integer exponents. If we are satisfied with this: okay!

But if we want a more deeper answer then ve have to justify that formula starting from a more general definition of an exponential with rational exponent.

For positve integers exponents a good definition can be:
$$
 \forall a \in \mathbb{R}: \quad a^0=1, \quad a^n =a\cdot a^{n-1} \quad \forall n \in \mathbb {N}
$$

From this definition we prove easily that 
$$
a^{n+m}=a^n\cdot a^m \quad \forall n,m \in \mathbb{N} ; \qquad a=1=a
$$
So we have a function $\exp_a:\mathbb{K} \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ such that:
$$
(1)\;\forall a\in \mathbb{K}:\quad \exp_a(0)=1, \quad \exp_a(1)=a, \quad \exp_a(n+m)=\exp_a(n)\exp_a(m) \; \forall n,m \in  \mathbb{N}
$$
Now we can adopt $(1)$ as a **definition** of the exponential function and use it to extend such function to other kinds of exponents, chosing $n,m \in \mathbb{K} $.

The definition is:

$$
(2)\;\forall a\in \mathbb{K}:\quad \exp_a(0)=1, \quad \exp_a(1)=a, \quad \exp_a(x+y)=\exp_a(x)\exp_a(y) \; \forall x,y \in  \mathbb{K}
$$

E.g., for an integer $n<0$ we see that our definition give:
$$
\exp_a\left( n+(-n)  \right)=\exp_a(0) = \exp_a(n)\exp_a(-n)=1 
$$
so $\exp_a(-n)$ must be the inverse of $\exp_a(n)$, and this fact justifies :
$$
a^{-n}=\dfrac{1}{a^n}
$$
Note that from $(2)$  we have also the rule:
$$
(a^n)^m = a^{nm} \; \forall n,m \in \mathbb{Z} 
$$
Now, if we want  an exponent $p \in \mathbb{Q}$, we have, for $p=m/n \Rightarrow np=m $:
$$
\exp_a(np)=\exp_a (m) \Rightarrow x^n=\left[exp_a(p)\right]^{\,n}=\exp_a(m) 
$$
so that $x$ is  the number such that $x^n=a^m$ i.e. $x=\sqrt[n]{a^m}$.

At last note that it does matter the choice of the field $\mathbb{K}$ in def. $(2)$, because the exponential function must have value in  $\mathbb{K}$ so, for negative integer exponents, $\mathbb{K}$ must be at least $\mathbb{Q}$, and for exponents  in $\mathbb{Q}$ the field $\mathbb{K}$ must be a suitable subfield of  $\mathbb{R}$ ( see 
[The exponential extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ is a proper subset of $\mathbb{C}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1006237/the-exponential-extension-of-mathbbq-is-a-proper-subset-of-mathbbc))

Comment: I don't know about the "only one continuous function" bit. Given a function defined only on the integers, there are many ways to extend it to a continuous function on the reals (or on the rationals, or on the complex numbers).

Comment: @Gerry :The claim refers to the fact that there exists only one ( non-trivial) solution of the functional equation $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ with $f(1)=a$, See e.g. :J.Aczél, Lectures on functional equations and their applications. The continuity being necessary when $\mathbb{K}$ is a complete space to avoid ''wild'' solutions.

Comment: Sure, but for that you want the functional equation to hold for all $x,y$ in the field. What you have written in your answer is only that it holds for all $x,y$ in the naturals.

Comment: good point! I wrote that we want to ''extend to other kinds of exponents'', but I've not specified what kinds.  I edit and change a bit the definition.

Comment: But after the edit, it still says there's only one continuous function on the field that satisfies the functional relation *on the naturals*, and that's plainly false. (Also, one of those $n$s on the right side of the equation wants to be an $m$.)

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Thanks,corrected typo.But I don't understand your first question. The condition $f(1)=a$ fix only one exponential function that, for any integer $n$, is exactly $a^n$.

Comment: I'm saying that, for any $a$, there are many functions, continuous on the reals, satisfying $f(n)=a^n$ for all natural numbers $n$.

Comment: but, as far as I know, only one of those functions is such that $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y) \forall x,y \in mathbb{R}$.

Comment: No kidding. But what you actually write is that there is only one continuous function satisfying ($f(1)=a$ and) $f(m+n)=f(m)f(n)$ for all natural numbers $m,n$, and that's just nonsense.

Comment: Thank you @Gerry. Now i've understand the point! (maybe I had some trouble because my english is not fluent). I have edit and I hope that now work properly.